# how to add item in custom sorted list?

Tags: c++, list

A really basic question about lists in C++ that I'm struggling with. I have a structure `Metadata` that have `prev`, `next` and `value`. I have a block `metadataBlock` which is already sorted by `value` and I want to add a new block `metadataBlockResult` in that list. What I did:

```
bool addedFlag = false;
Metadata* iterator = metadataBlock;
while (iterator != nullptr) {
    if (metadataBlockResult->getValue() < iterator->getValue()) {
        // What should be here?
        addedFlag = true;
        break;
    }
    iterator = iterator->getNext();
}

if (!addedFlag) {
    metadataBlockResult->setPrev(iterator);
    metadataBlockResult->setNext(nullptr);
    iterator->setNext(metadataBlockResult);
}
```

I can't seem to understand how to add the item between two items and handle all cases (start and end). How should I add the item?

Comment: when the list is empty you do `iterator->setNext(metadataBlockResult);` while *iterator* is NULL. You will never add the element at the end of the list, so in case it is greater than already present ones. *iterator* is a bad name

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid to use pen and paper to visualize the logic to be implemented:

[image: insert into doubly-linked list]

Here's some pseudocode with a possible implementation:

```
// 1. Find the position to insert newNode

Node *before = nullptr, *after = startOfList;
while (after != nullptr && after->value < newNode->value) {
    before = after;
    after = after->next;
}

// 2. Splice newNode in between before and after

newNode->prev = before;
newNode->next = after;
if (before != nullptr) {
    before->next = newNode;
} else {
    startOfList = newNode;
}
if (after != nullptr) {
    after->prev = newNode;
}
```